# Need optimization advice on my angular2 threejs app

Tags: javascript, three.js, angular

Last week i developed a small threejs angular2 app : https://third-view.herokuapp.com/

I have basic knowledge of both.

Now i am having following issues in the app.

1: Page loads slowly.

2: If I open my app in browser which is running on CPU, then after navigating to 2-3 pages, WebGLRenderer renders the scene very slowly. Stats-js shows fps drop. But if i use my nvidia graphic card to run chrome, it works perfectly.

When i tried the app using static html and javascript, it works perfectly on any CPU.

So far what i have got.

To decrease loading time, i will use CDN for static libraries like threejs, jquery, bootstrap....etc and low graphic images.

But i didn't found out any way to run the app properly on normal CPU.

I thought of manually call **cancelAnimationFrame** in **ngOnDestroy** of each angular2 component. but didn't help anyway.

Now i have 2 choices

1: Optimize the app.

2: Make the app using normal non angular approach(static html and javascript).

I want to optimize the app and need some advice.
Here's the source code : https://github.com/priyesh9875/third-view/tree/third-view-express

Thank you

**update** my laptop is HP 15 pavilion 204tx, 4gb ram i5 processor, 2gb nvidia 740m graphics

Comment: i think it's not about angular, you just have heavy content on your website and the casual medium spec PC's will just load it slow

Comment: I am sure 4gb ram and i5 processor should be enough to run basic app smoothly

Comment: Why downvote? I just asked for advise

Comment: i wasn't the one who give the down vote :)

Comment: you are not managing your GPU memory, clicking between 2 tabs i can fill up the memory in no time, make sure you dispose all textures, geometries etc when you are changinch scenes, i suspect it is even adding more objects(that are perfectly aligned in each other)

Comment: Thx for advice and I just checked in chrome dev tool. Memory keeps on building up. I tried many answers on stackoverflow, all said to dispose() all geometry and materials. I did that and also delete scene, camera, rendered whatever object I created in ngOnDestroy() function. But still memory keeps on building up. Can you plz tell me how exactly I can do that. And also isn't threejs and chrome's  job to freeup memory?

Comment: Priyesh, did you mange to fix your problem? I am experiencing the same. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Dino well not much, memory keeps growing. Only way is to refresh the page(design your app such that user refreshes the page). I haven't seen any threejs single page application yet.

Comment: Hi Priyesh, for your information my application crashes on Chrome but works well in Safari and rocks in Firefox. See if this is your case too and maybe it will point you in the right direction in fixing your problem. I will post any solution I might find in the meantime.

Comment: @Dino I use chrome for everything. May b it crashes when memory reaches its limit, but i haven't tested!. Happy to see any solution